# hypertarget{}{} does not create anchors when compiled with xelatex

Tags: xetex, hyperref, miktex

In my LaTeX document I define external anchors using `hypertarget{AnchorLabel}{AnchorText}` in order to open the resulting PDF document at a desired location. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter[First chapter - short title]{First chapter - long title}
\hypertarget{TestA}{AAA}
Some text
\clearpage

\section[First Section]{First Section - long title}
\hypertarget{TestB}{BBB}
Some further text
\clearpage

\subsection[A subsection - short title]{A subsection - long title}
\hypertarget{TestC}{CCC}
Some more text
\end{document}
```

The PDF generation is done using xelatex. The PDF file can be opened on the desired page e.g. using

```
evince --named-dest=TestC /path/to/file.pdf
```

(under Linux) or

```
Call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /a "nameddest=TestC" "C:\path\to\file.pdf"
```

under Windows.

Generation of PDF with correctly working anchors works fine on a Debian machine with XeTeX version 3.1.415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeXLive 2012 Debian), however does not work on a Windows machine with a current MiKTeX installation (XeTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)). The anchors seem to be broken or non-existent. Strangely enough, if compilation on the Windows machine is done using pdflatex instead of xelatex, everything seems to be fine.

Is it a bug in the current XeTeX version?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275739/named-destinations-by-hyperref-broken-for-xetex-3-14159265-2-6-0-99992-tex-live

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike, the workaround described there solves the problem. As far as I understand it's indeed a bug in XeTeX known since December 2015 and it is not MikTeX specific. What I still do not understand quite well is the proper place and procedure for reporting this and similar bugs in order to get them fixed. Has it already been taken care of and if not how and where do I do this?

Comment: Created a [ticket on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/132/).