# Create hypertarget with platex + dvipdfmx that can be opened from external pdf

Tags: hyperref, pdf, dvipdfmx, platex

The following link [Hyperref to external pdf that will open at particular label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/hyperref-to-external-pdf-that-will-open-at-particular-label) gives great answer for linking individual pdfs.
However it seems to NOT working for platex with dvipdfmx that is mostly used for Japanese documents.
Is there a way to create hypertarget with the engine, or necessary to use pdflatex which is not compatible with Japanese?

Comment: Do you mean named destination? (Japanese forum http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/tex/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=2071 may provide an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is the default setting of dvipdfmx. By default, the PDF destination are optimized, so they cannot be accessed from other files. If you disable the optimization, the hypertarget works.

Ref. dvipdfmx.cfg ($TEXMFDIST/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg)

```
%% Dvipdfmx Compatibility Flags
%%
%%   0x0002  Use semi-transparent filling for tpic shading command,
%%           instead of opaque gray color. (requires PDF 1.4)
%%   0x0004  Treat all CIDFont as fixed-pitch font.
%%           This is only for backward compatibility. Don't use that.
%%   0x0008  Do not replace duplicate fontmap entries.
%%           Dvipdfm's (not 'x') behaviour.
%%   0x0010  Do not optimize PDF destinations. Use this if you want to
%%           refer from other files to destinations in the current file.

%C  0x0000
```

So, you should invoke dvipdfmx as follows, to disable optimization of destinations inside the *target* file that is referenced:

```
dvipdfmx -C 0x0010 fileA
```

Alternatively, if you are using TeX Live 2016 or later, simply adding

```
\special{dvipdfmx:config C 0x0010}
```

to fileA.tex has the same effect.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275739/named-destinations-by-hyperref-broken-for-xetex-3-14159265-2-6-0-99992-tex-live is the same situation, since XeTeX uses xdvipdfmx, which shares the binary with dvipdfmx, as an output driver.

Comment: Great answer! By the way, are there any problems when it is disabled? Anyway, I'm putting `\special{dvipdfmx:config C 0x0010}` in my target file for the current purpose.

Comment: When the optimization is enabled, the target names are shortened (This is why references from external files are impossible). When the optimization is disabled, the original target names (e.g. "myhypertarget1" in fileA.tex you referred to) are preserved, which should mean that the file size may become bigger. Personally I don't think that is a serious problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I definitely disable the optimization without worry :)